# Is port an excluesive resourse in xmlrpc multithreading server?

Tags: c++, multithreading, port, rpc, xml-rpc

I'm writing a xmlrpc server with XMLRPC++ lib.I want to make it Multi-threaded on a single port,meaning that I'd have multiple threads working on various request received on a single port.
However,I'm not sure it'll work.Is the port a excluesive resourse?When I receive a request and start a thread,is it possible that I receive another request from the same port while the first thread's still working?